# What is the purpose of strongly typing the store in NgRx?

Tags: angular, store, strong-typing

CoreModule is an eagerly loaded module containing the state needed at application start.

```
import * as fromCore from './state/core.reducer';

@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    StoreModule.forRoot({ core: fromCore.reducer }),
```

DocumentModule is a lazy loaded module.

```
import * as fromDocument from './state/document.reducer';

@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    StoreModule.forFeature('document', fromDocument.reducer),
```

DocumentComponent injects the store.

```
import * as fromDocument from './state/document.reducer';

constructor(private store: Store<fromDocument.State>) { }
```

fromDocument.State extends the 'core' state.

```
import * as fromCore from '../../core/state/core.reducer';

export interface State extends fromCore.State {
    document: DocumentState;
}
```

This is an approach I see used everywhere, but I don't see any benefit to it. When I set it up so that fromDocument.State does not extend fromCore.State, I can still access the 'core' part of the state tree in DocumentComponent.

```
this.user$ = this.store.select(fromCore.getUser);
```

By injecting the store in a component I always have access to the complete state tree, regardless how I type the store. So what exactly is the purpose of strongly typing the store? Why not just use Store<any> everywhere? The only way I interact with the store object is store.select and store.dispatch so there is no typing benefit as far as I can see?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Specific point

In the specific case you mentioned, the typing will help with the overload of `select` that takes a mapping function as argument, e.g. `this.store.select(s => ....)`.

NgRx still let you do un-typed selection, though. Related discussion on GitHub about that : https://github.com/ngrx/store/issues/60

### Generally

Strong typing from TypeScript and other fancy stuff (and, to be fair, most features of all programming languages) **are not meant to**

- *automate validation* for your program
- act as some kind of *security feature* (prevent data leak)

They are meant instead as a *crutch for us poor human developers* to avoid doing the silly mistakes we usually write in our own code.

Example : like trying to call `user.namme` instead of `user.name` in an obscure, forgotten part of the code, that will lead to a cascade of bugs. Imagine it shows only some "undefined" and "login error" to the user, in a strange place, and only if he does 5 very specific actions in a certain order, a bit hard to trace back and reproduce.

This will be quickly detected by your compiler, before put in production, if you use strong typing.

Comment: This is not a question about strongly typing in general. It’s a very specific question about the NgRx store object requiring a type argument.

Comment: @pcmcoomans my bad if I missed your point. There is a related discussion on the typing of the store github here : https://github.com/ngrx/store/issues/60 . (Also, as a side comment, the pattern I saw usually is to inject the store in a Service, not a Component directly). If you do `this.store.select(s => ....)`, isn't it typed as per the generic type of the store ? (helping you while coding, with autocomplete and compilation error ?)

Comment: thank you that was exactly the info I was looking for. I've only been passing selectors into the select function. It does not matter how you type the store when you do that. But when you pass in a mapFn, the type indeed provides code completion.